# write a class in python that accepts parameteres

Tags: python

I am writing a simple class that will basically accept 3 parameters, execute a series of commands and return the result.

Now the problem is that i am not clear about how to write a proper class in Python (i use C++ mainly); so is kinda weird for me to figure out what and how to write the class.

I have 3 parameters: name, classID and objectType (all 3 strings type), i need to return a string with the results of the operation.

So far I wrote this:

```
class testClass(superclass):

def __init__(self, name="",classID="", objectType="" *kwargs):

    superclass.__init__(self, args, **kwargs)

    result = ""
    ...(do the operation with the parameters, if the result is positive return OK
        otherwise return KO)
```

Then i saved it as testClass.py and imported it in my main python program

The issue is that when i pass parameters i get an error saying that the global name "args" is not defined, on the superclass __init line

In C I would just write something like

```
class testClass 
{
    string name, classID, objectType;
}string
```

and the program would know that it must expect 3 parameters (and then deal in the constructor with the data verification and validation), but i cannot grasp how you tell Python the same thing.

If i can get to understand how to use Python in the way that it should be (and not translating code from a language to another), maybe i can avoid to get stuck like in this case :)

Any help is appreciate to shed some light on the subject.

Comment: Look here: `superclass.__init__(self, args, **kwargs)`. The variable `args` here is not defined. What does `superclass`' constructor accept?

Comment: The `def __init__` line is wrong, too. Missing a comma in front of `*kwargs`, which is actually positional arguments. Also he says "In C I would just write" and then posts invalid C++ code (why is there a `string` after `}`?). So this question needs a lot of cleanup because it's currently not even wrong.

Comment: What exactly are you using as a reference/tutorial to learn Python? Also, your terminology is quite flaky: classes don't "execute" and "return" stuff, but instead **define a data type**. You have an `__init__` **method** (which you use in place of a C++ constructor, but it doesn't work quite the same way behind the scenes) that will accept the parameters, and then you might have some **other** method that actually performs a calculation and returns a result. You would then **instantiate** the class and use the resulting **object**. `__init__` is not supposed to return a value.

Comment: It seems very likely that you *don't want a class at all*. Python being an object-oriented language absolutely does NOT mean that you're expected to stuff all your code into classes. The natural model for "a thing that accepts parameters, performs a calculation and returns a result" is - brace yourself - a function.

Comment: Santa, the constructor of the super accept a string.

Mike; why do you say that what i wrote is invalid C++ code? Any book shows a class that returns a string in the same way that i typed it: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Karl: the idea was to ask a question, not to explain the whole project A to Z with perfect details :) I admit that the terminology is not correct some time, but English is not my main language, and not every language use the English words for the terms; so gotta translate them and sometimes I get them wrong.

Comment: I just asked "how do i pass 3 parameters in Python"; and made a reference to C++; of course a class has a constructor and a distractor; private and public members and maybe functions and routines that spit out something, so the class can return something (or return nothing; maybe just write on a log, who knows); but I have no clue how it works in python, since I took the docs online and started to read them...that's all the documentation that i read :) I understand that the __init works like the constructor, but other than that I just assume how it may work, and that's why I asked the question

Comment: BTW Karl, I know the difference between a function and a class....Python is the 7th programming language that I've learned (or tried to learn) in the past 18 years :P A class can have a function that does what is needed, but a function by itself either must go in the main (ugh!) or you gotta stick in a class...or maybe python works differently? The old rule of 1 object 1 operation is still valid nowadays, so you don't wanna put everything in your main  file, am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the function definition thats like this `def __init__(self, name="", classId="", objectType="", *args, **kwargs):`.

What this defines besides the 3 known arguments (name, classId, objectType) is **args** which is a list of addtional arguments passed to the function, and **kwargs** which is a dictionary containing named arguments passed to the function.

With the above definition for your `__init__` you could call your class this way:

```
t = testClass("name", "class1", "Object", "value1", 11, scope="local", destroy=True)
```

Now that call would give us inside `__init__`

```
name = "name"
classId= "class1"
objectType = "Object"
args =  ["value1", 11]
kwargs = { 'scope': "local",
           'destroy': True }
```

Oh and lastly, *args, **kwargs is optional for any function definition. If like you mention you know you will only be passed 3 arguments, then you can remove the *args, **kwargs.

Comment: PErfect Arunkumar....that's exactly what i was looking for!

My idea is to pass the 3 parameters, and then in the __init__ i check if the values are correct and if they are correct then there is a function that does the magic and returns a string with the results; and between your comment and the one from agf I think that i have all that i need to clean up the class and be done :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to require 3 parameters, try:

```
def __init__(self, name, classID, objectType):
```

Since you haven't supplied defaults they're required. In standard Python, there is no way to tell a function what type of arguments to expect -- just try to use them as strings and then errors will be raised if they're not compatible with string operations. If you really want to check, you can do:

```
if not isinstance(name, str):
    raise TypeError
```

Do you actually need to call up to the superclass' `__init__`? If so, use [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super):

```
super(testClass, self).__init__()
```

If you want to pass any unknown parameters after the three required ones up to the superclass' `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, name, classID, objectType, *args **kwargs):
    super(testClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

`*args` is collecting any extra non-keyword arguments into the variable `args`. Notice `**kwargs` has two stars -- it's collecting keyword arguments into a [mapping / dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict). There is nothing special about `args` and `kwargs`, you have to fill them in as above, they're not filled in magically.